# How to use React Native code, which is available as a string, in my application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, dynamic

I have some react native code available in a string variable:

```
let customCode='<View><Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Hello World!</Text></View>'
```

How can I use this in my react native application and display the 'View' to the user.

Here's my code -

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default const SimpleComponent = () => {
  let customCode='<View><Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Hello World!</Text></View>'

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Hello World</Text>
      <View>{customCode}</View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I used the customCode variable in my return part like this

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>How are you</Text>
      <View>{customCode}</View>
    </View>
  );
```

but it just treats the customCode variable as a string instead of actual react native code.

Comment: A JSX parser should do the job (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jsx-parser - it probably doesn't need to be React Native specific). But it's probably better and safer to use Markdown and a markdown parser for this kind of case to avoid risk of malicious code injection (e.g. if the string contains `<Pressable onPress={() => downloadVirus()}>`). Or, use CodePush or Expo Updates. Also, don't add _new features_ "over the air" from your server like this - Apple and Google will de-list your app for bypassing their review process.

Answer (score 0):

```
let customCode=<View><Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Hello World!</Text></View>
```

and then

```
 <View>{customCode}</View>
```

no need for quotation marks

Comment: But I have the code as a string as it is coming from a backend server. And I have to show it dynamically. I don't have the code at compile time.

Comment: then brother, you are using a faulty approach, what's on ur mind? , maybe we can find a better solution

Comment: No  it's really common to serve dynamic content to React Native apps from a server. Otherwise you'd need a whole app store release just to refresh a "latest news " box... But normally people serve Markdown strings and parse them, not JSX. Or if they need to serve full-fat JSX, they use CodePush or similar, and push out full JS updates.

Comment: no brother, dynamic content is not handled in such ways, you provide your endpoint and fetch it and then render responses in your way that you want them to appear

Answer (score 0):

In React Native, you cannot directly render a string containing JSX code like you would in a web application.

Just make your customCode a component.